# Indent chapter title with titlesec

Tags: chapters, titlesec, chapter-page

[image]

I am using the following code to define the Chapters with the titlesec package in the book class and XeLaTeX.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\futura\huge\bfseries\raggedright}
{\thechapter\text{.}\hspace{30pt}}
{0pt}
{\Huge\MakeUppercase}
[\vspace{1ex}]
```

As indicated by the provided picture, I'd like to indent the whole text, i.e. no more text underneath the chapter number. I have tried adding hspace, adding a parbox etc. but I am unable to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Please don't just post a code fragment. Always make a small, but compilable test file so that people can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Try to delete the `[block]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newfontfamily{\futura}{Futura}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\futura\huge\bfseries}
{\makebox[\chapternumbersize][l]{\thechapter.}}
{0pt}
{\typesetchaptertitle}

\newcommand{\typesetchaptertitle}[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapternumbersize}{\raggedright\Huge\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\chapternumbersize}{60pt}% adjust to suit

\begin{document}

\chapter{Theoretische Betrachtungen}

Text of the chapter follows
Text of the chapter follows
Text of the chapter follows
Text of the chapter follows
Text of the chapter follows
Text of the chapter follows
Text of the chapter follows

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following is much simpler than egreg's solution. You just have to delete `[block]`!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newfontfamily{\futura}{Futura}

\titleformat{\chapter} % No need [block]
{\futura\huge\bfseries\raggedright}
{\thechapter.\hspace{30pt}}
{0pt}
{\Huge\MakeUppercase}
[\vspace{1ex}]    

\begin{document}

\chapter{Theoretische Betrachtungen}

\end{document}
```